# How to write a variable in a script from another script without sending the value of the variable?

Tags: bash, shell

Basically, I want to send a variable as $1 in another script without the value it has saved.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -e "#!/bin/bash\ncp ~/src/$1" > ~/asset/newfile.sh
```

So, that in the file newfile.sh it is written:

```
#!/bin/bash

cp ~/src/$1
```

Comment: Use single quotes instead of double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can escape the dollar sign with a backslash:

```
echo -e "#!/bin/bash\ncp ~/src/\$1"
```

Or, switch to single quotes:

```
echo -e '#!/bin/bash\ncp ~/src/$1'
```

Comment: Boo, hiss re: `echo -e` (vs showcasing `printf`, and thus demonstrating code that would reliably work across all POSIX shells)